# AND no SQL (Firebird)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS SET categoria = '001' WHERE marca = '1774'
```

Porém há mais de 400 marcas.. pensei em usar AND no where para fazer com várias marcas de uma vez, porém não vai, e com uma marca só vai. Há alguma maneira de encurtar isso pra não fazer 1 por 1?

Comment: Se usar o AND... uma marca pode ser dois valores diferentes ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Não seria `OR` (marca = 1 OR marca=2 OR ...) ou até mesmo `IN` (marca IN (1, 2, ...))?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a clausula `IN`

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS SET categoria = '001' WHERE marca IN ('1774', '1775', '1776')
```

Você pode também utilizar um sub-select ali para retornar o código das marcas que deseja, por exemplo, se você possuí uma tabela só de marcas:

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS 
   SET categoria = '001' 
 WHERE marca IN (SELECT CODIGO
                   FROM MARCAS
                  WHERE TIPO = 1)
```